# Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

This error appears in console on scene load:

> Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene. (Did you spawn new GameObjects from OnDestroy?)

I know it's because I `Instantiate` an object in an `OnDestroy` method  and I know [how to fix](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/169656/instantiate-ondestroy.html) this problem on application quit. But I don't know how to fix this on scene change with `SceneManager.LoadScene()`

Is there any method for this need, something like `OnSceneUnload`?

Comment: I think you more likely have a design issue. There seems to be contradiction in your code. OnDestroy creates a new object while switching scene. That does not sound suitable to me. I would rather store the info about the need for the object via PlayerPrefs and create the object in the new scene reading the player prefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)` like:

```
    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (Application.loadedLevelName == "MyNextScene") 
        {
            // Clean Up leaked objects
        }
    }
```

It is called when scene changes.

**UPDATE:**

Above suggestion was to create script that isnt cleaned up when new scene is loaded, so basicly you need to use something like this in this script:

```
void Awake() 
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Then store this not cleaned up objects in some collection of this script, and let it clean it up for you when scene changes.

Comment: Thanks! It does not seems to work. I added `void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level){isQuitting = true;}` on every script with a `OnDestroy` method and it still don't work (btw, it still works on application quit, and it's the same code)

Comment: Well what you really need to do is to add this magic method to any active MonoBeahaviour that lasts between scenes (like with `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);`)

Comment: @rap-2-h I eddited my answer, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar issue instantiating objects in OnDisable.

What worked for me was to check if the scene was still loaded in OnDisable. This returned false both when quitting the app/editor and when unloading the scene.

```
void OnDisable()
{
        if(!this.gameObject.scene.isLoaded) return;
       // Instantiate objects here
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Works in EditMode also 

Comment: Always wanted to know how to check if the game was "quitting" will try this. Thanks